# Finding the smallest max eigenvalues for related matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra, graph-theory, numerical-linear-algebra, spectral-theory, spectral-graph-theory

While messing around with a spectral approach to a graph coloring question, I happened upon a type of problem I hadn't seen before.

Suppose you have two symmetric $n$ x $n$ matrices in the form $$A= \begin{pmatrix}
&0&x_{1,1}&...&...&x_{1,(n-1)}\\
&x_{1,1}&0&x_{2,1}&\ddots&x_{2,(n-2)}\\
&\vdots &x_{2,1}&0&\ddots&\vdots\\
&\vdots &\ddots &\ddots&0&x_{(n-1),1}\\
&x_{1,(n-1)}&x_{2,(n-2)}&...&x_{(n-1),1}&0
\end{pmatrix}$$ and $$B=\begin{pmatrix}
&0&\left|x_{1,1}-1 \right|&...&...&\left|x_{1,(n-1)}-1 \right|\\
&\left|x_{1,1}-1 \right|&0&\left|x_{2,1}-1 \right|&\ddots&\left|x_{2,(n-2)}-1 \right|\\
&\vdots &\left|x_{2,1}-1 \right|&0&\ddots&\vdots \\
&\vdots &\ddots &\ddots&0&\left|x_{(n-1),1}-1 \right|\\
&\left|x_{1,(n-1)}-1 \right|&\left|x_{2,(n-2)}-1 \right|&...&\left|x_{(n-1),1}-1 \right|&0
\end{pmatrix}$$
with any $x_{i,j}=\begin{cases}
& 1\\
& 0
\end{cases}$, or, that is to say, $A+B$ is a matrix in the form $$A+B= \begin{pmatrix}
&0&1&...&...&1\\
&1&0&\ddots&\ddots&\vdots\\
&\vdots &\ddots &0&\ddots&\vdots\\
&\vdots &\ddots &\ddots&0&1\\
&1&...&...&1&0
\end{pmatrix}$$

Suppose that $\lambda_{1a}$ is the largest eigenvalue for matrix $A$ and $\lambda_{1b}$ the largest eigenvalue for matrix $B$.  How can I obtain the smallest possible $\lambda_{1a}$ and $\lambda_{1b}$ by manipulating the values of the entries in $A$ (which correspondingly change $B$)?

I know that for larger matrices, this will probably be impossible to analytically determine, but an approach for a numerical method has been difficult for me to come up with.  Considering that, if $A$ is empty, then $\lambda_{1b}$ will be its maximum value, it seems that the smallest largest eigenvalues for this system of matrices will be when $\lambda_{1a}\approx\lambda_{1b}$. What confuses me, though, is how to change the values in $A$ to most efficiently affect the desired changes in eigenvalues. Is there a name for this type of problem, or a best practice for approaching it numerically?

Thanks in advance for any info, input or ideas you can provide!

Comment: For a start it depends what you mean by "the smallest possible $\lambda_{1a}$ and $\lambda_{1b}$". Could you meand their sum? Their product?

Comment: Good question, sorry if that wasn't clear.  I mean that I want to simultaneously minimize the largest eigenvalue for both matrices, and since they are dependent on each other, that would imply that the difference between $\lambda_{1a}$ and $\lambda_{1b}$ is as close to zero as possible.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $\overline{G}$ is the complement of the graph $G$. Then 
\[
  A(G)+A(\overline{G}) = J-I
\]
(where $J$ is the matrix with all entries equal to one). If $n=|V(G)|$, this implies that
\[
  \lambda(G)+\lambda(\overline{G}) \ge n-1.
\]
We get equality here if $G$ is a regular self-complementary graph. In particular if we take $G$ to be the Paley graph on $n$ vertices then 
\[
  \lambda(G) = \lambda(\overline{G}) = (n-1)/2
\]
and your difference is zero. (Note that Paley graphs exist if and only if $n$ is a prime power congruent to 1 mod 4.)

Comment: Wonderful input, I hadn't thought about Paley graphs for some reason.  To clarify though, Paley graphs exist if and only if $n$ is a prime power congruent to 0 _or_ 1 mod 4, not just 1 mod 4.  I appreciate the response and your time!

Comment: No, you need $n$ congruent to 1 mod 4. This is also a necessary condition for a regular graph to be self-complementary.

Comment: Oh wow, my bad.  I must have gotten mixed up.  I should have spent more time checking my facts before posting that comment, my apologies Chris.